# Is there a simpler way to check user permissions against a method input?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a C# MVC Framework being passed objects by an Angular UI. On the C# side I am trying to check if the user is allowed to create the object by checking the passed in object properties. Is there a cleaner way to do this- like not having to call identity every time? Right now I have:

Object validating code from my C# controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<AppUser> UpdateUser([FromBody]AppUser au)
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        var auclaims = new ApplicationUser(identity);    
        if (!auclaims.CanModifyUser(au))
            return StatusCode(401, "invalid permissions");
        .....
        }
```

Comment: use policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Please note that a code of `401` implies you do not know who the user is (not authenticated) while a code of `403` says "we know who you are and you are not allowed to do this". So you should really return a 403, not a 401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create new class :

```
public class CheckPermission : ActionFilterAttribute {

    public string ArgName { get; }

    public CheckPermission(string argName)
    {
        this.ArgName = argName;

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {

        var controller = context.Controller as Controller;

        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)controller.User.Identity;

        var au = context.ActionArguments[ArgName] as AppUser;

        var auclaims = new ApplicationUser(identity);

        if (!auclaims.CanModifyUser(au)) 
            context.Result = controller.StatusCode(401, "You do not have permission to add a user to this company");

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Then put this attribute upon you action:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [CheckPermission("au")]
 public ActionResult<AppUser> UpdateUser([FromBody]AppUser au)
 {
        // focus on your business logic
 }
```

you can reuse this attribute for any action to check user permission.

This is to apply the concept of AOP.

Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx

Comment: .net core has this built in.